# Vue.js working with xml feed

Tags: jquery, xml, vue.js, vue-component, vue-resource

I starting working on my personal site using Vue.js. And now i'm suddenly stuck. I want to shot the five newest post om my Jekyll blog on the page.

That's why i'm looking in the `http://todayilearned.dk/feed.xml`feed.

But I can't figure out how to print the three variables in `console.log`.

How do i do that? (title, link and description.)

I keep getting this error.

> data functions should return an object. (found in component: )

```
  <script>
  var $ = require('jquery');

  export default {
      data: function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
         var feed = 'http://todayilearned.dk/feed.xml';
         $.ajax(feed, {
           accepts: {
             xml: 'application/rss+xml'
           },
           dataType: 'xml',
           success: function (data) {
             $(data).find('item').each(function () {
               var el = $(this);
               console.log('title      : ' + el.find('title').text());
               console.log('link       : ' + el.find('link').text());
               console.log('description: ' + el.find('description').text());
             });
           }
         });
       });
     }
 };;
```

The entire code. https://gist.github.com/mikejakobsen/bbe51bef07ae9cdb113501f9025838c7.pibb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because whatever processing you are doing, you should be doing in [beforeMount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount), like following

```
  <script>
  var $ = require('jquery');

  export default {
      data () {
        return {
          title: ''
        }
      },
      beforeMount () {
        var self = this
        $(document).ready(function () {
         var feed = 'http://todayilearned.dk/feed.xml';
         $.ajax(feed, {
           accepts: {
             xml: 'application/rss+xml'
           },
           dataType: 'xml',
           success: function (data) {
             $(data).find('item').each(function () {
               var el = $(this);
               self.title = el.find('title').text()
               console.log('title      : ' + el.find('title').text());
               console.log('link       : ' + el.find('link').text());
               console.log('description: ' + el.find('description').text());
             });
           }
         });
       });
     }
 };
```

[beforeMount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount) is one of many [Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) provided by vue where you can access data, computed properties, and methods. You can also choose other hook based on your requirement.

[data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) is where you define vue instance variable which can be used reactively in the template.

Comment: Thank you! But how do i then transfer the data from the beforeMount hook to the view? The view is within the same file? https://gist.github.com/mikejakobsen/bbe51bef07ae9cdb113501f9025838c7.pibb

Comment: @MikeJakobsen I have updated the answer with one sample, please check.